# How to make an animated gradient border around the vectorized image (Objective-C for iPad)?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, ios6, gradient

Could you please help me to find a right way to make an animated gradient border around the image like [this](http://happy-coloring.ru/en/img/bear-with-gradient-small.png)?

I have got vectorized image (Adobe Illustrator, EPS etc.). So, I would like to make a border which is turning around the object.

What direction should I looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Check this  [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7613906/ios-animate-dashed-rectangle-border) it is help me before and I think u can use the same logic to make yours animation.

By using shape-Layer:

```
 [shapeLayer setBounds:shapeRect];
    [shapeLayer setPosition:CGPointMake(160.0f, 140.0f)];
    [shapeLayer setFillColor:[[UIColor clearColor] CGColor]];
    [shapeLayer setStrokeColor:[[UIColor blackColor] CGColor]];
    [shapeLayer setLineWidth:1.0f];
    [shapeLayer setLineJoin:kCALineJoinRound];
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I'll try.

My border has rather difficult shape. How can I use the path described in the external file (EPS)?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your link. I can make a gradient filling now and marching ants separetly. But the question is: how to combine them?
I would like to make a continuous rounded line with gradient color around with coloring rotation. Kind a continuous gradient ants.
Thanks in advance