# Is it possible to animate a change in a UIView's lineDash stroke with Core Graphics/Animation?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, core-graphics, core-animation

I have a UIView subclass that does some drawing, and at one point calls `CGContextSetLineDash` to set the dash and gap information on the line stroke.

Is it possible to do this with an animation? If so, how? I find Core Graphics very confusing and I'm admittedly just getting started out with it.

Comment: Core Graphics is only really designed to do static drawing, there's nothing built in that will let you animate. You'll probably have to hook up a `CADisplayLink` to the `drawRect` and vary your line dashing, or try and achieve the same effect in Core Animation.

Comment: also, when you say animation, are you talking about animating the line dash spacing from a given value to another value? or are you talking about animating the path itself? I can create an example project for you with some explanation if you want.

Comment: Are you trying to animate the dashes? This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7613906/ios-animate-dashed-rectangle-border

Core Animation does kinda go hand in hand with Core Graphics and can accomplish a lot of animation tricks